# Having trouble running classes from other classes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to run `class AddTQuestions` from a def in `class AddTest` but it wont work!! 
It opens the window `AddTQuestions` for a split-second then closes it straight away?!

The code is shown here:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):               
        RunClassAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        RunClassAction.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(RunClassAction)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Why Wont this Woooorkkkkk')    
        self.show()

    def run(self):
        AddQuestion = AddTQuestions()
        AddQuestion.show()

class AddTQuestions(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AddTQuestions, self).__init__(parent)
        self.welldone = QtGui.QLabel('WellDone')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Press Me')
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.welldone)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        print("hello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "won't work" because you are not keeping a reference to the instance of `AddTQuestions` you created, and so it gets garbage-collected immediately after it is shown.

There are a number of different ways to fix this, but probably the best way for your situation is to use a `QDialog` instead of a `QMainWindow`, and then show the dialog using `exec`:

```
    def run(self):
        dialog = AddTQuestions()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            print('Accepted')
        else:
            print('Cancelled')

class AddTQuestions(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AddTQuestions, self).__init__(parent)
        self.welldone = QtGui.QLabel('WellDone')
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Press Me')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        ...
```

This has the bonus of also fixing the issue with the layout.